# Save full screenshot including bars

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having problems with the following code only takes a photo of my UITableView only and not the entire screen with the navigation and tab bars...

I  would like the full screen capturing including navigation and tab bars. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)view
{
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
}
```

Comment: which view are you passing in to capture?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [following](https://github.com/Moped/MPNotificationView/blob/master/MPNotificationView/MPNotificationView.m#L478) code worked for me a couple of months ago:

```
CALayer *layer = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].layer;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, scale);

[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: This works partly but cuts out the status bar.. any ideas to include status bar?

Comment: It's not possible. Only using private APIs, but then your app will be rejected.

Comment: Ok, interesting, can I remove the white strip along the top where the status bar seemed to be omitted from the screenshot?

Comment: Sure. Added link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 Version if any one needs

```
func getScreenShot() -> UIImage {

        let layer : CALayer = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer)!
        let scale : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
```